# Tomcat7 CentOS Service Start fail

Tags: java, tomcat, centos, tomcat7

I am having issues with auto-loading tomcat7. This is the init.d script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# chkconfig: 2345 80 20
# Description: Tomcat Server basic start/shutdown script
# /etc/init.d/tomcat7 -- startup script for the Tomcat 7 servlet engine

TOMCAT_HOME=/usr/local/tomcat7/bin
START_TOMCAT=/usr/local/tomcat7/bin/startup.sh
STOP_TOMCAT=/usr/local/tomcat7/bin/shutdown.sh

start() {
 echo -n "Starting tomcat7: "
 cd $TOMCAT_HOME
 ${START_TOMCAT}
 echo "done."
}

stop() {
 echo -n "Shutting down tomcat7: "
 cd $TOMCAT_HOME
 ${STOP_TOMCAT}
 echo "done."
}

case "$1" in

start)
 start
 ;;

stop)
 stop
 ;;

restart)
 stop
 sleep 10
 start
 ;;

*)
 echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"

esac
exit 0
```

When starting like so:

```
>service tomcat7 start

Starting tomcat7: 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
done.
```

Tomcat does not seem to not be able to load a properties file from apache commons. Does anyone know why this is ?

```
The file is:
user-config.properties
found in:
/usr/local/tomcat7/conf
```

Everything works fine when running directly like so:

```
/usr/local/tomcat7/bin/startup.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

**Run Through:**

%> service tomcat7 start
Starting tomcat7: Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
done.

```
%> ps -aux |grep tomcat
Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.8/FAQ
root     26657 60.4  8.5 7181652 1385552 pts/0 Sl   16:11   0:15 /usr/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/tomcat7/endorsed -classpath /usr/local/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat7 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat7 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat7/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
root     26706  0.0  0.0 103252   844 pts/0    S+   16:11   0:00 grep tomcat
```

**Now I load the webpage with causes the error**

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
type Exception report
message java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerErrorcom.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)com.ftw.tme.filter.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:130)

root cause

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerErrorcom.ftw.tme.authentication.service.impl.AuthenticationServiceImpl.<init>(AuthenticationServiceImpl.java:27)com.ftw.tme.rest.AuthenticationRestService.<init>(AuthenticationRestService.java:38)sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)com.sun.jersey.server.spi.component.ResourceComponentConstructor._construct(ResourceComponentConstructor.java:245)com.sun.jersey.server.spi.component.ResourceComponentConstructor.construct(ResourceComponentConstructor.java:233)com.sun.jersey.server.impl.resource.PerRequestFactory$PerRequest._getInstance(PerRequestFactory.java:182)com.sun.jersey.server.impl.resource.PerRequestFactory$AbstractPerRequest.getInstance(PerRequestFactory.java:144)com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationContext.getResource(WebApplicationContext.java:239)com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:83)com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)com.ftw.tme.filter.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:130)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerExceptionjava.lang.String.replace(String.java:2180)com.ftw.tme.commons.db.util.tmeConfigUtils.<clinit>(tmeConfigUtils.java:71)com.ftw.tme.authentication.service.impl.AuthenticationServiceImpl.<init>(AuthenticationServiceImpl.java:27)com.ftw.tme.rest.AuthenticationRestService.<init>(AuthenticationRestService.java:38)sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)com.sun.jersey.server.spi.component.ResourceComponentConstructor._construct(ResourceComponentConstructor.java:245)com.sun.jersey.server.spi.component.ResourceComponentConstructor.construct(ResourceComponentConstructor.java:233)com.sun.jersey.server.impl.resource.PerRequestFactory$PerRequest._getInstance(PerRequestFactory.java:182)com.sun.jersey.server.impl.resource.PerRequestFactory$AbstractPerRequest.getInstance(PerRequestFactory.java:144)com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationContext.getResource(WebApplicationContext.java:239)com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:83)com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)com.ftw.tme.filter.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:130)






%> ps -aux |grep tomcat
Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.8/FAQ
root     26657 19.2  8.6 7718532 1397424 pts/0 Sl   16:11   0:15 /usr/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/tomcat7/endorsed -classpath /usr/local/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat7 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat7 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat7/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
root     26727  0.0  0.0 103252   844 pts/0    S+   16:12   0:00 grep tomcat
[user@localhost bin]#
```

Comment: Do you actually get an error? What does it look like? Note that this is an application problem and not a Tomcat problem.

Comment: well it all seems to work fine application wise when we load tomcat via /usr/local/tomcat7/bin/startup.sh.    if started the service way then it simply fails. I have no idea why this would make any difference ?

Comment: Check the difference in output when you run "ps". Perhaps the current working directory has something to do with it. When it fails, do you get an error message of any kind? If so, post it.

Comment: I have updated the question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an NPE in your own code:

```
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
  java.lang.String.replace(String.java:2180)
  com.ftw.tme.commons.db.util.tmeConfigUtils.<clinit>(tmeConfigUtils.java:71)
  com.ftw.tme.authentication.service.impl.AuthenticationServiceImpl.<init>(AuthenticationServiceImpl.java:27)
  com.ftw.tme.rest.AuthenticationRestService.<init>(AuthenticationRestService.java:38)
```

Comment: but why would it only occur when we start tomcat via the service ?

Comment: @DevilCode I'm not sure -- how would I know... it's *your* code. Why not modify `tmpConfigUtils` to figure out what is `null` in that case?